# XSLT 2 | Saxon HE 9.5.1-2 | Initial Template Selection

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon

The following XSLT does the job of transforming the input to output seamlessly on *Stylus Studio*:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:param name="COEP_FilePath"/>

    <xsl:template name="main>
        <xsl:element name="actualUpload" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="(not($COEP_FilePath) and not(string($COEP_FilePath)))">
                    <xsl:message terminate="yes">One or more Input Parameter(s) not supplied!</xsl:message>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:variable name="COEPData" select="unparsed-text($COEP_FilePath)"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="Tokenized_COEPData" select="tokenize($COEPData, '\r\n')"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="Period" select="normalize-space(tokenize(tokenize($COEPData, '\r\n')[1], '~')[3])"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="FiscalYear" select="normalize-space(tokenize(tokenize($COEPData, '\r\n')[1], '~')[6])"/>                    
                    <xsl:variable name="Orders" as="element(Orders)*" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
                        <Orders>
                            <xsl:for-each select="$Tokenized_COEPData">
                                <xsl:variable name="valueInContext" select="tokenize(., '~')"/>
                                <Order>
                                    <!--<period>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($valueInContext[3])"/>
                                    </period>
                                    <finYear>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($valueInContext[6])"/>
                                    </finYear>
                                    <actualRecId>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($valueInContext[2])"/>
                                    </actualRecId>-->
                                    <cur>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($valueInContext[9])"/>
                                    </cur>
                                    <amount>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="if (ends-with(normalize-space($valueInContext[4]), '-')) then concat('-', substring-before(normalize-space($valueInContext[4]), '-')) else normalize-space($valueInContext[4])"/>
                                    </amount>
                                    <internalOrderNum>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($valueInContext[5])"/>
                                    </internalOrderNum>
                                </Order>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </Orders>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <period>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$Period"/>
                    </period>
                    <finYear>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$FiscalYear"/>
                    </finYear>
                    <actuals>
                        <xsl:for-each-group select="$Orders/*" group-by="concat(internalOrderNum, '|', cur)">
                            <actualRec id="{internalOrderNum}">
                                <cur>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="cur"/>
                                </cur>
                                <amount>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/xs:decimal(amount))"/>
                                </amount>
                            </actualRec>    
                        </xsl:for-each-group>
                    </actuals>              
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For this to work, I had to specify the initial template value to main in Scenario Properties/Processor section of Stylus Studio. The XSLT will be employed in a java application [iWay Service Manager which uses Saxon HE 9.5.1-2 library] and I am unable to figure out to a method to specify the initial template. Maybe there exists a JVM option that I could leverage but I am looking up on the internet, no hits yet.

In the meantime, my attempt to workaround the problem to replace user-defined template name "main" to "xsl:initial-template", in response to noticing to a mentioning about this to work on other SO discussions, did not prove successful. Not even in Stylus Studio as this uses an older version of Saxon lib as well. I realize that the Saxon HE library in use requires an upgrade to latest maintenance release. However, doing so, will have a wider impact on the java application as we are bound to regression test of existing solutions/etc.

For want of time, I would like to explore only the following two options:

1) Using a configuration file where initial template name could apparently be specified. I though need some advise on how to enable this on the java application;

2) Advise on re-writing the XSLT so that it doesn't bump into parse error as a result of the use of unparsed-text() function;

For what its worth, here is an example input:

```
1000~1234567890~007~            12345.05-~ORDUMMYORD1        ~2019~A~04~EUR  ~          ~0212~
1000~0987654321~007~             12345.05~ORDUMMYORD1        ~2019~S~04~EUR  ~ABCDEFGHIJ~0212~
1000~6789054321~007~                  20-~ORDUMMYORD3        ~2019~A~04~EUR  ~          ~0184~
```

and it's corresponding output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<actualUpload>
  <period>007</period>
  <finYear>2019</finYear>
  <actuals>
    <actualRec id="ORDUMMYORD1">
      <cur>EUR</cur>
      <amount>0</amount>
    </actualRec>
    <actualRec id="ORDUMMYORD3">
      <cur>EUR</cur>
      <amount>-20</amount>
    </actualRec>
  </actuals>
</actualUpload>
```

Please suggest. Thx.

**EDIT 1: 13:39 CET**

I've revised the XSLT to the following that work the problem around:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:param name="COEP_FilePath"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="actualUpload" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="(not($COEP_FilePath) and not(string($COEP_FilePath)))">
                    <xsl:message terminate="yes">One or more Input Parameter(s) not supplied!</xsl:message>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:variable name="COEPData">
                        <root>
                            <xsl:value-of select="unparsed-text($COEP_FilePath)"/>
                        </root>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="Tokenized_COEPData" select="tokenize($COEPData/root, '\r\n')"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="Period" select="normalize-space(tokenize(tokenize($COEPData/root, '\r\n')[1], '~')[3])"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="FiscalYear" select="normalize-space(tokenize(tokenize($COEPData/root, '\r\n')[1], '~')[6])"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="Orders" as="element(Orders)*" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
                        <Orders>
                            <xsl:for-each select="$Tokenized_COEPData">
                                <xsl:variable name="valueInContext" select="tokenize(., '~')"/>
                                <Order>
                                    <!--<period>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($valueInContext[3])"/>
                                    </period>
                                    <finYear>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($valueInContext[6])"/>
                                    </finYear>
                                    <actualRecId>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($valueInContext[2])"/>
                                    </actualRecId>-->
                                    <cur>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($valueInContext[9])"/>
                                    </cur>
                                    <amount>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="if (ends-with(normalize-space($valueInContext[4]), '-')) then concat('-', substring-before(normalize-space($valueInContext[4]), '-')) else normalize-space($valueInContext[4])"/>
                                    </amount>
                                    <internalOrderNum>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($valueInContext[5])"/>
                                    </internalOrderNum>
                                </Order>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </Orders>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <period>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$Period"/>
                    </period>
                    <finYear>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$FiscalYear"/>
                    </finYear>
                    <actuals>
                        <xsl:for-each-group select="$Orders/*" group-by="concat(internalOrderNum, '|', cur)">
                            <actualRec id="{internalOrderNum}">
                                <cur>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="cur"/>
                                </cur>
                                <amount>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/xs:decimal(amount))"/>
                                </amount>
                            </actualRec>
                        </xsl:for-each-group>
                    </actuals>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It though would be nice, if the below is commented on. Thx.

> 1) Using a configuration file where initial template name could apparently be specified. I though need some advise on how to enable this on the java application;

Comment: The Saxon 9.5 documentation at http://saxonica.com/documentation9.5/index.html#!configuration/configuration-file suggests that the Saxon configuration file has an attribute `initialTemplate` on the `xslt` element. So using a Saxon configuration file you should be able to specify an initial template. I doubt there is a JVM option for that. As the problem seems to be specific to using the Saxon version from another tool (iWay) I would at least try to ask people with knowledge on that tool, not sure whether you will find anyone on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thx @MartinHonnen I will post the question to our [iWay] product division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the functional XSLT for reference-sake. The variable `COEPData` now has an XML tag surrounding the unparsed-text() thereby allowing processor to continue with the operation.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" exclude-result-prefixes="xs"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:param name="COEP_FilePath"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="actualUpload" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="(not($COEP_FilePath) and not(string($COEP_FilePath)))">
                    <xsl:message terminate="yes">One or more Input Parameter(s) not supplied!</xsl:message>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:variable name="COEPData">
                        <root>
                            <xsl:value-of select="unparsed-text($COEP_FilePath)"/>
                        </root>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="Tokenized_COEPData" select="tokenize($COEPData/root, '\r\n')"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="Period" select="normalize-space(tokenize(tokenize($COEPData/root, '\r\n')[1], '~')[3])"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="FiscalYear" select="normalize-space(tokenize(tokenize($COEPData/root, '\r\n')[1], '~')[6])"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="Orders" as="element(Orders)*" exclude-result-prefixes="xs">
                        <Orders>
                            <xsl:for-each select="$Tokenized_COEPData">
                                <xsl:variable name="valueInContext" select="tokenize(., '~')"/>
                                <Order>
                                    <!--<period>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($valueInContext[3])"/>
                                    </period>
                                    <finYear>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($valueInContext[6])"/>
                                    </finYear>
                                    <actualRecId>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($valueInContext[2])"/>
                                    </actualRecId>-->
                                    <cur>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($valueInContext[9])"/>
                                    </cur>
                                    <amount>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="if (ends-with(normalize-space($valueInContext[4]), '-')) then concat('-', substring-before(normalize-space($valueInContext[4]), '-')) else normalize-space($valueInContext[4])"/>
                                    </amount>
                                    <internalOrderNum>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space($valueInContext[5])"/>
                                    </internalOrderNum>
                                </Order>
                            </xsl:for-each>
                        </Orders>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <period>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$Period"/>
                    </period>
                    <finYear>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$FiscalYear"/>
                    </finYear>
                    <actuals>
                        <xsl:for-each-group select="$Orders/*" group-by="concat(internalOrderNum, '|', cur)">
                            <actualRec id="{internalOrderNum}">
                                <cur>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="cur"/>
                                </cur>
                                <amount>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/xs:decimal(amount))"/>
                                </amount>
                            </actualRec>
                        </xsl:for-each-group>
                    </actuals>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```